# Misleading XCTAssertEqual With Accuracy macro wording or a bug?

Tags: ios, xctest

This code

```
XCTAssertEqual(1, 1.1, accuracy: 0.1)
```

evaluates to a failed test with a message

> XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy failed: ("1.0") is not equal to ("1.1") +/-
>   ("0.1")

I was expecting that this test evaluates to 1.1 is equal to 1 and test pass green.
I was expecting that this test evaluates to 1.1000000001 is not equal to 1 and test pass red.

Is it a bug or expected behavior?

If the behavior is correct then coud you explain why?

Comment: The message looks great to me. What do you not like about it?

Comment: @matt I was expecting 1.1 would pass and 1.100000000001 would not

Comment: No, 1.1 is just a tiny bit too big. See also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html as always

Answer (score 2):

The difference should be less than accuracy

```
        XCTAssertEqual(1, 1.1, accuracy: 0.11)
```

Comment: For you, the name of the method is misleading or it's the method behavior error?

Comment: I think it is not a bug, or behavior error, I checked the other languages, but in this case I think the error message is wrong. just it

Comment: Floating point numbers not exact as written. 0.1 is not exactly that. Write a little test and print or log all numbers - probably can see your value higher in the 10th decimal place.